# Rails active storage, rotate image before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I have a website that allows users to upload images in bulk, however some of those images need to be rotated.

I know there is the ability to rotate an image when displaying it using:

`image.variant(rotate: -90)`

However how can I on a particular image rotate it and save the rotated version so that when displaying this image it will by default be the correct orientation?

I have read through the active storage rails guide but its it doesn't really cover transforming images on the way up, only on the way down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option in ActiveStorage to do this, but you can use minimagick to manipulate the images. You're able to do this with after_save or after_update callbacks